# Implementing a Band-Pass Filter from Scratch

Tags: filters, convolution, finite-impulse-response, frequency-domain, bandpass

I am trying to implement a band-pass filter from scratch. [Here](https://tomroelandts.com/articles/how-to-create-simple-band-pass-and-band-reject-filters) is an article which I thought explained the nuts and bolts of how to build one; the author combines a low-pass with a high-pass filter (convolving both) to create a band-pass filter. I applied it to a mixture of sine waves, but the result was not satisfactory.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, linspace, pi
from pylab import figure, plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel, subplot, savefig, xlim, ylim
from scipy import fft, arange

def plotSpectrum(y,Fs):
    n = len(y) # length of the signal
    k = arange(n)
    T = n/Fs
    frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
    frq = frq[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

    Y = fft(y)/n # fft computing and normalization
    Y = Y[range(n/2)]

    plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
    xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
    ylabel('|Y(freq)|')

Fs = 150.0;  # sampling rate
Ts = 1.0/Fs; # sampling interval
t = arange(0,30,Ts) # time vector

ff = 0.2;   # frequency of the signal
y = sin(2*pi*ff*t)
ff = 0.8;   # frequency of the signal
y = y + sin(2*pi*ff*t)

figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,y)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(2,1,2)
plotSpectrum(y,Fs)
savefig('out1.png')

fL = 0.1
fH = 0.3 
N = 33
n = np.arange(N)

hlpf = np.sinc(2 * fH * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hlpf *= np.blackman(N)
hlpf = hlpf / np.sum(hlpf)

# Compute a high-pass filter with cutoff frequency fL.
hhpf = np.sinc(2 * fL * (n - (N - 1) / 2.))
hhpf *= np.blackman(N)
hhpf = hhpf / np.sum(hhpf)
hhpf = -hhpf
hhpf[(N - 1) / 2] += 1

hp = np.convolve(hlpf, hhpf)
filtered = np.convolve(y, hp)

t2 = np.linspace(0,30.,len(filtered)) # time vector
figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t2, filtered)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(2,1,2)
plotSpectrum(filtered,Fs)
savefig('out2.png')
```

For the original signal:

[image]

I get an output like this:

[image]

To confirm I could filter this signal, I used a butterworth filter,

```
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

filtered = butter_bandpass_filter(y, fL, fH, Fs, order=2)
```

That worked fine (although I had to play around with the order a little bit, higher orders of this filter does not work either). What is wrong with the first filter?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to make a real bandpass filter (assuming you know how to make a low pass filter) is multiply the coefficients of your prototype low pass filter by $cos(2\pi f_c nT)$ where $f_c$ is the desired center frequency of your passband and T is the sampling interval for your coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The following Matlab codes were based on Steven W. Smith's DSP book,

http://www.gomatlab.de/window-sinc-filter-t19156.html

which I converted into Python;

```
import numpy as np

def hamm(window_size):
    N = window_size;
    output = np.zeros((N, 1));
    if np.mod(N, 2) == 0 :
        m = np.fix(N / 2)
        n = m
    else:
        m = np.fix(N / 2)+1; 
        n = m-1; 
    window = 0.54 - 0.46 * np.cos(2*np.pi*(np.arange(m)) / (N-1))
    tmp1 = window[:int(m)]
    tmp2 = window[np.arange(int(n)-1,-1,-1)]
    return np.hstack((tmp1,tmp2))

def sinc_filter_low(order, fc1, fs):
    Fc1 = fc1 / np.float(fs) 
    M  = order
    B = np.zeros((M+1, 1))
    window = hamm(M+1)
    for i in range(M+1):
        if 2 * i == M:
            B[i] = 2*np.pi*Fc1
        else:
            tmp1 = 2*np.pi*Fc1 *(i-(M/2.))
            tmp2 = (i-(M/2.))
            B[i] = np.sin(tmp1) / tmp2
        B[i] = B[i] * window[i]
    return B / np.sum(B)

def sinc_filter_high(order, fc1, fs):
    Fc1 = fc1 / np.float(fs) 
    M  = order
    B = np.zeros((M+1, 1))
    window = hamm(M+1)
    for i in range(M+1):
        if 2 * i == M:
            B[i] = 2*np.pi*Fc1
        else:
            tmp1 = 2*np.pi*Fc1 *(i-(M/2.))
            tmp2 = (i-(M/2.))
            B[i] = np.sin(tmp1) / tmp2
        B[i] = B[i] * window[i]
    B = B / np.sum(B)
    B = -B
    B[(M/2)] = B[(M/2)] + 1
    return B

def sinc_filter_band(order, fc1, fc2, fs):
    M = order
    A = sinc_filter_low(order, fc1, fs).T[0]
    B = sinc_filter_high(order, fc2, fs).T[0]
    output = A+B
    output = -output
    output[(M/2)] = output[(M/2)] + 1.
    return output
```

These work fine.